# How to specify any/unknown/variant type in GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript, static-typing

Is there a way to specify an unknown type in GDScript?

GDScript docs use the type `Variant` for this (for example in [Array.count](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-count) method).

Say, I'd like to write an identity function. I can do it like so:

```
func identity(x):
    return x
```

But I'd like to declare that both the parameter type and return value could be anything. Something like:

```
func identity(x: Variant) -> Variant:
    return x
```

This doesn't work though. `Variant` is not a known type name. I tried various names, bot nothing seems to work.

Is the only option to leave off the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only option is to not specify the type.

This function:

```
func identity(x):
    return x
```

Takes `Variant` and returns `Variant`.

---

There is a `Variant` class defined in Godot in C++. Which, as you have found out, we cannot use it by name in GDScript.

Please notice that the docs use a notation based on C++. For instance `int count (Variant value)` does not only differ from GDScript because of `Variant`, but also in that you specify the type after the parameters not before the name, also you use `func`.

This is how `int count (Variant value)` looks in GDScript: `func count(value) -> int:`, and this is the C++ definition: `int Array::count(const Variant &p_value) const` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/array.cpp#L191)). *Compare the C++ definition with the one on the documentation.*

For another example, this is how `Array duplicate (bool deep=false)` looks like in GDSCript: `func duplicate(deep:bool=false) -> Array:`, and this is the C++ definition: `Array Array::duplicate(bool p_deep) const`. ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/array.cpp#L222)). *Notice the C++ definition does not indicate the parameter will be optional, that information is added for the script binding.*

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the deep explanation.